# EasyPHP - Devserver Vs Webserver for a local websites

Tags: web, webserver, local, easyphp, devserver

Is it acceptable to use the EasyPHP DevServer to host a local websites used by many other user on the same network ?

I Know it is suppose to be only a developpement environnement but is it really  necessary to use the Webserver if all user are in the local network?

Thanks a lot

Daniel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use for easyphp for multiple users, i still us it for 10-20 users without problem

Comment: Thx a lot exactly what i wanted to know

Comment: You mean with the devserver or webserver version

Answer (score 1):

The dev server isn't as powerful as the web server from my understanding however it can be done if it works for what you are doing. Not sure what else I can add than it will be fine.

Comment: do you think it can handle 4-5 user connected at the same time ?

Comment: You should be fine with 4-5.

Comment: Are you happy with answer?

Comment: Just waiting to see if someone have try it before and his review !